# Mockito and JUnit5 dependency testing problem

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

I have a class named Secret() and it has a associated class named Word(). This class Secret() handles a word that it receives from the Word() class through a method named getWord().
The problem is that I want to mock that getWord() method for test, but I can't. I should get a true assertion, but I get a false assertion

The Secret class:

```
public class Secret {

private String secret;
private Word word;

public Secret(){
    this.word = new Word();
    this.secret = word.getWord();
}

public String getSecret(){
    return this.secret;
}

//more methods... 
}
```

The Word class:

```
public class Word {

private String word;

public Word(){
    this.word = getFromFileRandom();
}

public String getFromFileRandom(){
    Random random = new Random();
    switch(random.nextInt(3)) {
        case 0:
            return "aabb";
        case 1:
            return "ccdd";
        case 2:
            return "eeff";
    }
    return "";
}

public String getWord(){
    return this.word;
}
}
```

...and the Test class

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class Secretmethod Test {

@Mock
Word word;

@Test
public void test() throws IOException {
    String stringMocked = "secreta";
    when(this.word.getWord()).thenReturn(stringMocked);
    Secret secret = new Secret();
    assertThat(secret.getSecret(), is("secreta"));
}
}
```

Thanks community!

Comment: Try using powermockito.whenNew() for Word class

Comment: thanks for answering, how do you use powermockito.whenNew()? I'm going to investigate via google

Comment: PowerMockito.whenNew(Word.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(word);
 NOTE: here 'word' is ur mocked object.

Comment: Thanks a lot DKS! I try it and tell you!

Comment: Hi DKS, i can't try with powermockito, but thank you for comment!

Answer (score 2):

The `Word` instance in your `Secret` class is not the mocked one, your `Secret` class creates a new one each time it is instanciated.

Create a new constructor in your `Secret` class :

```
public Secret(Word word){
  this.word = word;
  this.secret = word.getWord();
}
```

And pass your mock in your test method :

```
@Test
public void test() throws IOException {
  String stringMocked = "secreta";
  when(this.word.getWord()).thenReturn(stringMocked);
  Secret secret = new Secret(this.word); // pass word mock here
  assertThat(secret.getSecret(), is("secreta"));
}
```

Comment: I would like to do it without adding a new constructor, is it possible?

Comment: Although I don't recommand it, but yes, If you want to do this you can use PowerMockito like this : whenNew(Word.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(myWordInstance); myWordInstance being either a mock or an instance that you create.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new `Word` instance within the `Secret` constructor which is not mocked.
By annotating the `Word` member within the test class with `@Mock` Mockito creates a mocked instance of `Word`.

You have to bring the mocked `Word` instance into your `Secret` instance.e.g. via the constructor

```
public class Secret {

    private String secret;
    private Word word;

    public Secret(Word word){
          this.word =  word;
          this.secret = word.getWord();
     }
 ....
```

Comment: Yes, that has worked for me, but I would like to be able to do it without going through a parameter in the constructor. ¿it's possible?

Comment: You may use Dependency injection to inject an instance of Word. Done e.g. by Spring. Do you use Spring?

Comment: but, with powermockito.whenNew() it's posible?

Comment: I did not use power powermock yet, it could work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `Reflection`, which is not usually good - but not really matters for testing:

```java
String stringMocked = "secreta";
when(this.word.getWord()).thenReturn(stringMocked);
Secret secret = new Secret();

Field wordField = Secret.class.getDeclaredField("word");
wordField.setAccessible(true);
wordField.set(secret, this.word);

assertThat(secretB.getSecret(), is("secreta"));
```